# How do redirect from URL1 to URL2 on a MAC Yosemite OS ?

Tags: url, redirect

I have a URL1 which is my production URL. 
I have a URL2 which will point my test server

I have a MAC OS which is made a WIFI hotspot and my mobile/Laptop is connected to the WIFI hotspot ( LAN ) .

What I need is : 
       With the help of a mobile/Laptop if I type URL1 in my browser  it should be redirected to URL2 ( My Test server ).

Answer (score 0):

/etc/hosts and dnsmasq can only map a hostname to an IP. So, in order to do this you need to man-in-the-middle the DNS request.

To do this, install Bind and configure it. Then you need to point your system DNS to you new Bind install (the default homebrew Bind install will forward unknown request so this won't break any normal queries).

If you have home brew:

`brew install bind`

In `/usr/local/etc/bind/named.conf` (or a wherever brew installs named.conf). Append a zone entry at the bottom of the file, you shouldn't need to otherwise edit the file.

Not sure what URL you want to map but this would map the top level domain ".sky" (like .com).

```
zone "sky" {
    type master;
    file "/usr/local/etc/bind/sky";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     localhost. admin.sky. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;

sky.  IN  NS  localhost.
tech  IN  CNAME tech.remaptothis.com.
```

This will map "tech.sky" to "tech.remaptothis.com" for all DNS requests (browser, ssh, etc). Modify this record as needed. See references on Bind to create more specific examples.

Now, updated your system DNS to point to 127.0.0.1

[image: System Preferences]

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at this

http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/

Modify your hosts file.